# After matching first found occurrence stop reading

Tags: c#

I have something like :

```
string lines = "yes no \nmaybe no"


  foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains("no"))
               {
                 //do whatever here
               }
        }
```

I want it to stop reading after the first `no` occurrence.Should I use something else instead of `Contains` ? Or is there a way to solve it how it is?

Comment: if is not a loop , so what you want to stop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an alternative, you can also use the `break;` keyword. This will allow you to exit a loop, and in your case once a condition is met.

```
string lines = "yes no \nmaybe no"

foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains("no"))
               {
                 // condition is met, let's exit the foreach loop
                 break;
               }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the part of a string until the first occurrence of `"no"`, you can use `Substring` with `IndexOf` method:

```
var firstPart = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf("no"));
```